# i need to find words in a user inputed sentence from a textfile containing keywords to answer the users query

Tags: vb.net

hello I am doing my programming GCSE course work in visual basics and have gotten stuck on task 2. I need to find words in a user entered string and find words which match with words in a text file and then give advice to that question. For example if the user says "my phone screen is cracked" I need to take the words phone, screen, and cracked which all link together and answer the user based on that. So from the users question I can tell that the device is a phone, the problem is around the screen, and the actual issue is that the screen is cracked. Id have to find these words in a text file and then give the relevant advice which would be in this case replace your phone screen. So basically what I am asking is how I am supposed to find words in a users question from a text file and if there are linking words then give advice to it.

Some automated troubleshooting programs identify certain keywords in the customer’s query to provide
potential solutions to the query.
For example, ‘There is no display on my mobile phone screen.’
The keywords ‘display’ and ‘phone’ would link to common problems with a phone display.

Comment: That's an interesting task... What have you tried so far ? Where are you stuck exactly ? SO is not your free homework doing service, please show what you have tried, and somebody will help you to go one step forward.

Comment: well I am not sure what I am supposed to use to search a user string for words in a text file. that's the main thing id like to know.

Comment: We can't provide an answer to your question as it's way to broad. You're going to have to do some research and come back when you have a more specific problem.

Comment: You forgot to ask a specific programming question